# Did Adi Shankaracharya establish Sringeri Peetam after destroying an existing Buddhist monastery?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

[In his book State of mind](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=y_z_8ImnviEC&pg=PT62&lpg=PT62&dq=Suddhanvan&source=bl&ots=sjsZRHQD6e&sig=ACfU3U1se7L_qminQ3rJ3_TG2Ukq3uIKyw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA_azE8LviAhVJf30KHRwVA7cQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=ramhar%20bhavani&f=false), Manu Ranjish said that Adi Shankara established Sringeri mutt after destroying an existing Buddhist monastery in that place. what do the records maintained by the Srigeri mutt or other records say about this?

Comment: This particular article was taken apparently from the writings of Late Prime Minister Jawaharlal Nehru.  Late Prime Minister Jawaharlal Nehru was known for his leniency towards Communism and Western way of thinking and Hindu bashing.  I for one do not want to buy his theory.

Comment: @UdayKrishna: May be .  However, there is difference between leniency towards Communism and day to day politics.  He was heading Congress Government at the centre.

Comment: There is no evidence that Adi Shankara established any mutt, leave alone the Sringeri mutt. There is no evidence for the existence of the Sringeri mutt before 12th-13th century CE.